# How to display user a message on session timeout

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm implementing an adapter base authentication and trying the session timeout functionality I have updated "worklight.properties"and session timeout is working.

So whenever there is session time out or user clicks logout the logout function is called in CustomLoginModule. This works as expected but is there any way I can find in this logout methods why this method was invoked I mean user clicked logout vs session time out. And also how can I pass this info to the client side.

We have a requirement to display user message on session time out.

MobileFirst 7.1

Comment: @Idan Adar can you help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is no method provided by IBM MobileFirst to differentiate between a logout made by a user action (clicking "logout") to a logout that happened due to a timeout. This is custom functionality you will need to implement on your own.

If you a user clicks on "logout", store this action as a boolean flag and display the appropriate action.

Based on the value of the flag, you can then decide what message to display in case of a session timeout.